# Implementation of a time-domain solution of a transfer function

Tags: filters, transfer-function

I have the the following transfer function (TF):

$$
G(s) = \frac{b_2 s^2 + b_1 s + b_0}{a_3 s^3 + a_2 s^2 + a_1 s + a_0}
$$

I want to program the numerical solution of the underlying system of ODEs myself and compare it to MATLAB's `lsim`.

This TF should be equivalent to the system of ODEs:
[image]

Then, I solve it using some differential equations code in Julia, using $u(t) = 1$ as input. This yields $\dot u(t) = 0$ and $\ddot{u}(t) = 0$, so the effect of $b_1$ and $b_2$ are not visible in my implementation. However, `lsim` from MATLAB gives different results, and the effect of $b_1$ and $b_2$ is visible.

Here an example (with a lower order TF):
[image]

Does somebody see the error?

Comment: Note that $\dot u(t) = 0$ and $\ddot{u}(t) = 0$ only holds for $t\neq 0$ (assuming the input is switched on at $t=0$).

Comment: You are right, thank you.